# Sequence Diverging: Where's My Mistake?

Tags: sequences-and-series

**EDIT: Question answered; I misread my own handwriting when copying my notes into LaTeX. Thanks!**

I'm trying to show that $a_{n}$ diverges. The equation I arrive at does not diverge. Where did I go wrong in my calculation?

Here's my work:

[image]

Comment: Second line. You imply $4^n=4\cdot n$.

Comment: $4^{n} \neq \sqrt{16n^{2}}$

Comment: Your second step is wrong, $(4^n)^2 \neq 16n^2$ but rather $4^{2n}$.

Comment: Re: edit...It's okay, xisk; don't feel bad. I think we've all "been there, done that"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third step

$$4^n\neq \sqrt{16n^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Look at the second sentence in your work: the line where you incorrectly "move" from $4^n$ to $\sqrt{16n^2} = 4n$.

And clearly, $4^n \neq 4n$. So...it follows that

$$4^n \neq \sqrt{16n^2} = 4n$$

$$4^n = \sqrt{4^{2n}} = \sqrt{16^n}$$

Comment: Thumbs up - OP got it! +1

Comment: Yes, indeed! That's what counts!

Answer (score 1):

$$4^n=\sqrt{4^{2n}}=\sqrt{16^{n}}\neq \sqrt{16n^2}$$

To prove the divergence:

$$a_n=\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\sim_\infty \frac{4^n}{n}$$
and I think that you know that the last sequence is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

You change $4^n$ to $\sqrt {16n^2}$ in the denominator .